# Closing all modals on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a timeout system for my angularjs app. On timeout I will be presenting the user with a timeout modal. The problem that I am having is with other modals that are already open, the timeout modal appears on top of the existing modal. I am looking for some suggestions on how I can close all the existing modals before opening the timeout modal. I am using the $modal service.

```
timeoutModal = $modal({
templateUrl: 'components/common/timeout.html',
                controller: 'TimeoutController as time',
                backdrop: 'static',
                prefixEvent: 'timeoutMessage',
                show: false
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$modalStack.dismissAll();
```

usage

```
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modalStack){

    // ...

    $scope.closeAll = function(){
        $modalStack.dismissAll();
    };
)
```